# Ok to use form element to persist search filters?

Tags: html, forms, conventions

I have a web page with search filters to narrow the results.  You can click on a result to go to its details page, but if you used the browser's 'back' button to return to the search results, the filters all disappeared.  Is it bad practice to wrap the filter options in a "FORM" element so that they'll persist?

before:

```
<div class="sort-results classes">
        <select id="select-classes" name="sort-classes">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Sort by</option>
            <option value="price-ascending" data-order="asc" data-sort="class-price">Price: Lowest</option>
            <option value="price-descending" data-order="desc" data-sort="class-price">Price: Highest</option>
            ...
        </select>
        </div>
```

after:

```
<div class="sort-results classes">
     <form>
        <select id="select-classes" name="sort-classes">
            <option selected="selected" value="">Sort by</option>
            <option value="price-ascending" data-order="asc" data-sort="class-price">Price: Lowest</option>
            <option value="price-descending" data-order="desc" data-sort="class-price">Price: Highest</option>
            ...
        </select>
      </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think it's quite common practice to provide filter options in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` element is a form element. So in reality you *should* be wrapping them in a form. Also since your users are submitting data that's yet another reason for it to be in a form.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that (wrapping your form elements in a form).